# Nginx on ubuntu server for node.js app

Tags: node.js, nginx

[image: vm ss]

Here's my node txt file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

I can access my website via vm public `ip:port` but I can't figure out nginx config to get it to work without the port.

There are no errors displaying in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change your `listen` attributes to the `default_server`:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name 0.0.0.0; # your ip
}
```

Then restart your nginx

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

And you should be good to go!

Comment: I did resolve this, the problem was that I didn't open the port 80 on my router, just the 3000. Thank you for the answer tho :)